# How do I alter the URL of a primary_links menu item in drupal 6?

Tags: routes

I have already tried doing this in theme_preprocess_page() in template.php and this works if I output the array to the browser but the menu itself remains unchanged.

I have also tried using hook_menu_alter() but again this does not change the primary links.

Where am I going wrong here?